# Make last view fit to bottom of screen

Tags: android, layout

is there any possibility to change the properties of the last view in the layout to change its size to fit to the bottom of the whole screen (in any screen density).

Here is a sample image of my layout:

[image]

The layout contains a ScrollView with a LinearLayout as only child. The last item in this LinearLayout is a TableView with a grey gradient as background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try setting `layout_height` of your items to `"fill_parent"` and change their sizes via changing `layout_weight` property, that should work.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. The main problem was that a other view had its height set to "fill_parent" and destroyed the whole layout first. Changed that and now it is OK.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the grey part to stick to the bottom you should put weight=1.0 and wrap content for height on the view that is above that one (the white area).

Answer (score 0):

Checked it again on similar layout. The main work does the property `android:fillViewport="true"` Which

> Defines whether the scrollview should stretch its content to fill the viewport

More infos: [ScrollView.html#attr_android:fillViewport](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#attr_android%3afillViewport)